# Email Address Validation in Android on EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, email-validation

How can we perform `Email Validation` on `edittext` in `android` ? I have gone through google & SO but I didn't find out a simple way to validate it.

Comment: android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches();

Answer (score 90, accepted):

To perform Email Validation we have many ways,but simple & easiest way are **two methods**.

**1-** Using `EditText(....).addTextChangedListener` which keeps triggering on every input in an `EditText box` i.e email_id is invalid or valid

```
/**
 * Email Validation ex:- tech@end.com
*/


final EditText emailValidate = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textMessage); 

final TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text); 

String email = emailValidate.getText().toString().trim();

String emailPattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-z]+\\.+[a-z]+";

emailValidate .addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() { 
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { 

    if (email.matches(emailPattern) && s.length() > 0)
        { 
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"valid email address",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // or
            textView.setText("valid email");
        }
        else
        {
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Invalid email address",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //or
            textView.setText("invalid email");
        }
    } 
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    // other stuffs 
    } 
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    // other stuffs 
    } 
});
```

**2-**  Simplest method using `if-else` condition. Take the EditText box string using getText() and compare with pattern provided for email. If pattern doesn't match or macthes, onClick of button toast a message. It ll not trigger on every input of an character in EditText box . simple example shown below.

```
final EditText emailValidate = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textMessage); 

final TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text); 

String email = emailValidate.getText().toString().trim();

String emailPattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-z]+\\.+[a-z]+";

// onClick of button perform this simplest code.
if (email.matches(emailPattern))
{
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"valid email address",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
else 
{
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Invalid email address", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: This is not a valid email pattern. fails on test_04@yahoo.co.in.

Comment: @JijoThomas thank you.

Comment: not working for email  "contact@yehipay.co.in"

Answer (score 802):

Java:

```java
public static boolean isValidEmail(CharSequence target) {
    return (!TextUtils.isEmpty(target) && Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(target).matches());
}
```

Kotlin:

```
fun CharSequence?.isValidEmail() = !isNullOrEmpty() && Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(this).matches()
```

Edit: It will work On Android 2.2+ onwards !!

Edit: Added missing `;`

Comment: +1 for using built-in function. I would also replace `target == null`with `TextUtils.isEmpty(target)`.

Comment: this functionality doesn's validate if i use swipe option while typing any alternative please?

Comment: one line solution `return !TextUtils.isEmpty(target) && Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(target).matches();`

Comment: Good one.Compared to add email pattern individually

Comment: You shouldl also add the annotation: `@Contract("null -> false")` add add the import: `import org.jetbrains.annotations.Contract;`

Comment: This built-in pattern is unfortunately incomplete. For example, "a@a." would pass. Check this question for a "good enough for most" and an RFC822 compliant answer.

Comment: or a single liner `boolean result =  !TextUtils.isEmpty(target) && android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(target).matches();` :)

Comment: @MPelletier well, I tested it myself, and "a@a." will not pass

Comment: 1 upvote for using built-in function.

Comment: Very nice .I upvoted .

Comment: This doesn't work properly anymore. A valid email should be mason@日本.com but and this pattern matcher will return false.

Comment: According to RFC5321 section 4.5.3.1.1, the maximum total length of a user name or other local-part is 64 octets. But `Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS` allows input of local part of maximum 256 characters. Any reason of this? (There is a private fields `EMAIL_ADDRESS_LOCAL_PART` which follows the 64 octets limit.)

Comment: I would use `isBlank` not `isEmpty` for you cannot have empty space in emails.

Comment: Wouldn't this one alone `Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(target).matches()` be enough?

Answer (score 45):

I did this way:

Add this **method** to **check whether** **email address** is **valid** or **not**:

```
private boolean isValidEmailId(String email){

    return Pattern.compile("^(([\\w-]+\\.)+[\\w-]+|([a-zA-Z]{1}|[\\w-]{2,}))@"
              + "((([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\\.([0-1]?"
              + "[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\\."
              + "([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\\.([0-1]?"
              + "[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])){1}|"
              + "([a-zA-Z]+[\\w-]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,4})$").matcher(email).matches();
     }
```

Now check with **String** of **EditText**:

```
if(isValidEmailId(edtEmailId.getText().toString().trim())){
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Valid Email Address.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}else{       
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "InValid Email Address.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

**Done**

Comment: This one works for me because it's accepting "user@gmail.com.ph"

Answer (score 40):

Use this method for validating your email format. Pass email as string , it returns true if format is correct otherwise false.

```
/**
 * validate your email address format. Ex-akhi@mani.com
 */
public boolean emailValidator(String email) 
{
    Pattern pattern;
    Matcher matcher;
    final String EMAIL_PATTERN = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";
    pattern = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_PATTERN);
    matcher = pattern.matcher(email);
    return matcher.matches();
}
```

Comment: this catches the most for me

Comment: marks these as invalid  "plainaddress",
                "@domain.com",
                "あいうえお@domain.com",
                "email@domain",
                "email@111.222.333.44444",
                "email@domain..com"

Answer (score 12):

Try this:

```java
if (!emailRegistration.matches("[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-z]+\.[a-z]+")) {
 editTextEmail.setError("Invalid Email Address");
}
```

Comment: This won't work for emails with multiple dots in domain like a@woof.co.za . Also it matches things with no dots like name@gmailcom

Comment: There you go, fixed your regex to include the literal dot instead of "accept any character here" dot.

Answer (score 10):

```
public static boolean isEmailValid(String email) {
    boolean isValid = false;

    String expression = "^[\\w\\.-]+@([\\w\\-]+\\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}$";
    CharSequence inputStr = email;

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(expression, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputStr);
    if (matcher.matches()) {
        isValid = true;
    }
    return isValid;
}
```

Comment: this worked perfectly for me,may be the expression makes the difference..

Answer (score 9):

Use this method to validate the EMAIL :-

```
 public static boolean isEditTextContainEmail(EditText argEditText) {

            try {
                Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[_A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$");
                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(argEditText.getText());
                return matcher.matches();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Let me know if you have any queries ?

Answer (score 6):

try this

```
public static final Pattern EMAIL_ADDRESS_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(

              "[a-zA-Z0-9\\+\\.\\_\\%\\-\\+]{1,256}" +
              "\\@" +
              "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\\-]{0,64}" +
              "(" +
              "\\." +
              "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\\-]{0,25}" +
              ")+"
          );
```

and in tne edit text

```
final String emailText = email.getText().toString();
EMAIL_ADDRESS_PATTERN.matcher(emailText).matches()
```

Comment: This is android pattern and accepting 5125945@12.2121. Do you have any solution regarding this scenario

Answer (score 6):

This is a sample method i created to validate email addresses, if the string parameter passed is a valid email address , it returns true,  else false is returned.

```
private boolean validateEmailAddress(String emailAddress){
    String  expression="^[\\w\\-]([\\.\\w])+[\\w]+@([\\w\\-]+\\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}$";  
       CharSequence inputStr = emailAddress;  
       Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(expression,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);  
       Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputStr);  
       return matcher.matches();
}
```