# I am validationg a form using textutils

Tags: android, eclipse, email, android-edittext, textutils

i am validating a registration form using textutils class which contains Name , City, Phone, Email,User ID,Password. But its showing only on the first edittext which is name. I also wanna validate email format how to do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Email Address Validation in Android on EditText](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12947620/email-address-validation-in-android-on-edittext)

Comment: but wen i run my app it shows validation on the first edittext only

Comment: @(if(TextUtils.isEmpty(City)){
    city.setError("");
   city.requestFocus();
   return;}
    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(phone.getText()))
    {
    phone.setError("");
    phone.requestFocus();
    return;}
    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email.getText()))
    {
    email.setError("");
    email.requestFocus();
   return;}
   if(TextUtils.isEmpty(userid.getText()))
    {
    userid.setError("");
   userid.requestFocus();
   return;
    }
   
   
     if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password.getText()))
    {
    password.setError("Please enter YouPassword");
    password.requestFocus();
    return;
    })

Comment: you already accepted answer.. it means you got your solution...

Comment: @Prag's but its not working

Comment: whats problem with my answer ??@user3853169 i am using in my project and works fine

Comment: its showing some errors...

Comment: than you can ask me show error and update your question with code

Comment: post it in question...not in comment...it not readable proper..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem is That You Are Using **`return`** statement in your code..
So if any of this condition is true it will stop checking for another condition....

so Remove return statement from each if condition..

Try This..

```
    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(City))
    { 
        city.setError(""); 
        city.requestFocus(); 
    } 
    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(phone.getText())) 
    { 
        phone.setError(""); 
        phone.requestFocus(); 
    } 
    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email.getText())) 
    { 
        email.setError(""); 
        email.requestFocus(); 
    } 
    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(userid.getText())) 
    { 
        userid.setError(""); 
        userid.requestFocus(); 
    } 
    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password.getText())) 
    { 
        password.setError("Please enter Your Password"); 
        password.requestFocus(); 
    }
```

This may help you...

Comment: Thanx allott sir..can u also tell me how to check for mail id format that itsvalid or not.?

Answer (score 1):

One line solution

```
public boolean isValidEmail(CharSequence target) {
  return !TextUtils.isEmpty(target) && android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(target).matches();}


if(isValidEmail(userid.getText().toString())){
   userid.setError("Enter valid Email ID"); 
   userid.requestFocus();

 }
```