# check valid E-mail on EditText with regex operation like in C#

Tags: android, regex, android-edittext

hello guys is android support regex operation like C# or its exist with different name if it is can you tell me what is it and what i want is to do regex operation to check if this is valid e-mail on EditText ?

Comment: actually i am making some research for it but could not find anything i am new android developer if you can tell me the keyword that i need to search for it

Comment: there are a lot of answer does all the answers works?

Comment: well this [which explains why not to use regex.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1819142/how-should-i-validate-an-e-mail-address) explains that if email address is _user@gmail.com.nospam_ regex operation fails, the same regex expression which meets the [RFC](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2822#section-3.4.1)

Comment: you can refer this [textbox email address validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12947620/email-address-validation-in-android-on-edittext) or this [which explains why not to use regex.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1819142/how-should-i-validate-an-e-mail-address)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: How can I validate EditText input?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763022/android-how-can-i-validate-edittext-input)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public boolean emailValidator(String email) 
    {
        Pattern pattern;
        Matcher matcher;
        final String EMAIL_PATTERN = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";
        pattern = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_PATTERN);
        matcher = pattern.matcher(email);
        return matcher.matches();
    }
```

Try this. Pass the string which has to be validated to emailValidator function

```
        if(emailValidator(editText.toString()))
        {
            Log.d("Success", "yes");
        }
```

Comment: Doesn't match `me@localhost`

Answer (score 1):

Android provide inbuilt email pattern matcher so use that 
this code double check for blank email and email validation :) short  and sweet

```
public boolean isValidEmail(CharSequence strEmail) {
    return !TextUtils.isEmpty(strEmail) && android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(strEmail).matches();}
```