# Android email validation doesn't work

Tags: java, android

I'm new in Android programming and Java and it's very difficult to understand.

I have an editText field for the email that a user can enter. I get the input with this:

```js
final EditText loginEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginEmail);
```

No I'm checking if this field is empty or not. I'm doing this with this little if:

```js
if (loginEmail.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
  loginEmail.setError("Please enter a E-Mail Address!");
} else if () {
  loginEmail.setError("Invalid E-Mail Address!");
} else {
  //Do a thing if is valid...  
}
```

After the first `if` I want to check if the input is a valid email or not, but don't know how to deal with this.

I've tried it with the answer from this post: [Email Address Validation in Android on EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12947620/email-address-validation-in-android-on-edittext)

but I don't know how to use this method...

Thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use :

```
if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(loginEmail.getText().toString()).matches()){
    loginEmail.setError("Please enter a Valid E-Mail Address!");
}else {
    //email is valid
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks buddy. I'm happy

Comment: Consider accepting answer if helped! Happy coding :)

Comment: Yes, but I had to wait until 10 minutes are over ;) Before I can accept this

Answer (score 1):

Add the method from the other post to your class.
Then use this:

```
String email = loginEmail.getText().toString();
if (email.isEmpty()) {
    loginEmail.setError("Please enter a E-Mail Address!");
} else if (!isValidEmail(email)) {
    loginEmail.setError("Invalid E-Mail Address!");
} else {
  // Do a thing if is valid...  
}
```

Comment: The other answer shows the short way; mine shows how to use another method so I'll leave it here for now.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
String email_string = loginEmail.getText().toString();
if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(email_string) && android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email_string).matches()) {
    //valid emailID
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if entered text is empty and match with email pattern.

```
String emailPattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-z]+\\.+[a-z]+";

String email = loginEmail.getText().toString();

if (email.isEmpty() && email.matches(emailPattern)) {
    loginEmail.setError("Please enter a E-Mail Address!");
} else 
    loginEmail.setError("Invalid E-Mail Address!"); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**WORKING !!!!**

We have simple Email pattern matcher now

```
private static boolean isValidEmail(String email) {
        return !TextUtils.isEmpty(email) && android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Source: This is the code from one of the StackOverflow Answer for email validation using java.

```
public static boolean isEmailValid(String email)
    {
        Pattern pattern;
        Matcher matcher;
        final String EMAIL_PATTERN = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";
        pattern = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_PATTERN);
        matcher = pattern.matcher(email);
        return matcher.matches();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare this string format globally

`final String EMAIL_PATTERN = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";`

Now match the patter from text

`if ((!email_a.getText().toString().trim().matches(EMAIL_PATTERN))) 
{
    email_a.setError("Invalid email");
}`
Enjoy Coding :)