# How can i validate email in android?

Tags: android

> What's wrong with my email validation??

```
TextInputLayout useremail_layout = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.email_layout);
String email = "";
String emailPattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-z]+\\.+[a-z]+";
if (email.matches(emailPattern)&& email.length()>0) {
    useremail_layout.setError("valid address");
} else  {
     useremail_layout.setError("invalid email");
     Email.setError(null);  
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12947620/email-address-validation-in-android-on-edittext check this out

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try this my friend

```
 String emailAddress = etSignInEmail.getText().toString().trim();

 if (android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(emailAddress).matches()) {
     useremail_layout.setError("valid Email address");
}
else{
       useremail_layout.setError("invalid Email address");
}
```