# regular expression to validate string of characters that are not consecutive or repetitive for password field

Tags: android, regex, kotlin

I am trying to validate a password with those characteristics but I can't find a regex that can fulfill this condition.

In case you couldn't and you had an idea of ​​how to do that validation in kotlin/android it would be very helpful, thanks.

Comment: Please define what you mean by "consecutive" and "repetitive". For example, is `'acefhj'` consecutive (because of `'ef'`)? Is `'bxxar'` and/or `'bxarx'` repetitive (because of `'x'`)?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the below code to kotlin. Basically add a regex then use a onTextChangedListener to see if the text that has already been entered conforms to the regular expression mentioned before

```
String emailPattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-z]+\\.+[a-z]+";

emailValidate .addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() { 
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { 

    if (email.matches(emailPattern) && s.length() > 0)
        { 
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"valid email address",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // or
            textView.setText("valid email");
        }
        else
        {
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Invalid email address",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //or
            textView.setText("invalid email");
        }
    } 
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    // other stuffs 
    } 
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    // other stuffs 
    } 
});
```

Code Source: [Stackoverflow answer on email validation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12947622/13533028)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```
fun checkPassw(value: String): Boolean {
    val regex = Regex("^(?!.*(\\w)\\1).+$")
    return regex.matches(value)
}
```