# android email validation

Tags: java, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How should I validate an e-mail address on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1819142/how-should-i-validate-an-e-mail-address-on-android)

I used this:

```
Pattern.matches("^(.+)@([^@]+[^.])$", email)
```

it didn't work when I enter `asdf@asdf` , why pelase?

Comment: What does "it didn't work", mean?

Comment: @Code-Guru it means it doesn't see it wrong

Comment: What doesn't see what wrong? Please provide some concrete details such as compiler errors or output.

Comment: @Code-Guru, I think he means that it returns true when email="asdf@asdf" and Fernando expected false.

Comment: yes but I am bad english, sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Pattern.matches("^(.+)@([^@]+[^.]).([^.])$", email)
```

It works for emails like this:

```
name@name.com
```

Comment: +1, question is asking the reason why his doesn't work, you might want to add that in answer.

Comment: @tottiroma They two methods work , thanks