# Could not find class javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext

Tags: android

I'm using example from this link http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0452.html but I'm getting error: `Could not find class javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext` Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thats because  jars use core libraries. Android does not support all J2SE packages, but rather a subset of it: http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html