# how to do email validation in Edit text in android

Tags: android, regex, android-edittext

I have three edit text to get values getting Email is one of them and I cant validation of specific validation of Email text so any one can suggest me how to do this...

my code is ....

```
        String Tomaail="feedback@earthcorporation.co.in";
        String Name=name.getText().toString();
        String Mail=mail.getText().toString().trim();
        String Phone=phone.getText().toString();
        String Feedback=feedback.getText().toString();
        String emailPattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-z]+\\.+[a-z]+";

        if(Name.compareTo("") == 0 || Mail.compareTo("") == 0 || Phone.compareTo("") == 0 || Feedback.compareTo("") == 0)
        {
            if(Name.compareTo("") == 0)
            {
            name.setError("Enter Name");
            }
            else if (Mail.matches(emailPattern)  || Mail.compareTo("") == 0) 
            {
                mail.setError("Enter valid Address");
            }
            else if(Phone.compareTo("") == 0)
            {
                phone.setError("Enter Your Phone No.");
            }
            else
            {
                feedback.setError("Enter your Feedback");   
            }

            Toast.makeText(feedback.this,"Enter All Data",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
            else
            {
```

Comment: if you really think my answers is ri8 than plz upvote and mark as ri8

Comment: u r ri8 any other user bro

Comment: see the code you are using `else if(Mail.matches(emailPattern)` you should use **`else if(!Mail.matches(emailPattern)`** you forgot the `!` sign i think.

Comment: best method here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20883093/email-validation-on-edittext-in-android/27758740#27758740

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest method will be to use the inbuilt methods:

```
if(!android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(target).matches())
{
    mail.setError("Enter valid Address");
}
```

or you can do email validation using a regular expressions like this:

```
private static final String EMAIL_REGEX = "^[_a-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";
```

and validate it like this

```
......
else if (!Mail.matches(EMAIL_REGEX)) 
{
    mail.setError("Enter valid Address");
}
....
```

or you can also try the inbuilt matcher:

**[EDIT]:** changed `REGEX` to avoid CAP chars.

**[NOTE]:** make sure you have **`!`** sign inside `if` otherwise you will suffer reverse effect.

Hope it helps. `:)`

Answer (score 2):

```
public final static boolean isValidEmail(CharSequence target) {
    if (target == null) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(target).matches();
    }
}
```

If email Address is Valid Then it will Return True other Wise false

Answer (score 0):

Always start variable names with a lowercase letter.

If you need to check if a string is empty use either `string.isEmpty()` or `string.length() == 0`. If the string can be null, use `TextUtils.isEmpty(string)`. `String.compareTo("") == 0` is very bad.

And finally, for checking email validity use `Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(emailString).matches()`

Answer (score 0):

return android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(target).matches();