# How to verify email input in android settings

Tags: android, android-settings, edittextpreference

How can I verify a user enters email address in a `EditTextPreference` for android setting ?

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9355899/android-email-edittext-validation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Email Validation on EditText](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24969894/android-email-validation-on-edittext)

Comment: I think what the author means is to validate the email entered in `EditTextPreference` before saving it to preference

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should I validate an e-mail address?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1819142/how-should-i-validate-an-e-mail-address)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the way, You can use `inputType` in `EditText` to validate the input as email by the system!

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText" />
```

You can use the default utility to validate!

```
 boolean isEmailValid(CharSequence email) {
            return android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email)
                    .matches();
```

Answer (score 2):

Import [org.apache.commons.validator.routines.EmailValidator](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/EmailValidator.html) as one of your dependencies then use this method `EmailValidator.getInstance().isValid("editText_email")`.

It does the necessary *RegEx* checks to validate if the email is valid or not.

Answer (score 0):

You must read it from `SharedPreference` like this.

```
String email = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getString("your_pref_name","default_value")

if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
    //Perform operation on Email
} else {
   //Show error
}
```

### Listening to Preference Changes

If you want to listen to Preference changes, you must register a `OnPreferenceChangeListener` on your `Preference` and handle the inputs inside `onPreferenceChange()`.