# Android EditText validation - Email Address

Tags: java, android, validation

Hi this following code working properly, now i want know how can i add email validation when user register, and where to add those codes, if anyone knows please integrate with my codes (show me where to add those validation code)

```
package com.prinsapps.whatson;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.prinsapps.library.DatabaseHandler;
import com.prinsapps.library.UserFunctions;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class Register extends Activity {


/**
 *  JSON Response node names.
 **/


private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
private static String KEY_UID = "uid";
private static String KEY_FIRSTNAME = "fname";
private static String KEY_LASTNAME = "lname";
private static String KEY_USERNAME = "uname";
private static String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
private static String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";
private static String KEY_ERROR = "error";

/**
 * Defining layout items.
 **/

EditText inputFirstName;
EditText inputLastName;
EditText inputUsername;
EditText inputEmail;
EditText inputPassword;
Button btnRegister;
TextView registerErrorMsg;


/**
 * Called when the activity is first created.
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.register);

/**
 * Defining all layout items
 **/
    inputFirstName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fname);
    inputLastName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lname);
    inputUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.uname);
    inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pword);
    btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register);
    registerErrorMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.register_error);



 /**
 * Button which Switches back to the login screen on clicked
 **/

    Button login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bktologin);
    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Login.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            finish();
        }

    });

    /**
     * Register Button click event.
     * A Toast is set to alert when the fields are empty.
     * Another toast is set to alert Username must be 5 characters.
     **/

    btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

             if (   ( !inputUsername.getText().toString().equals("")) && 
                    ( !inputPassword.getText().toString().equals("")) &&
                    ( !inputFirstName.getText().toString().equals("")) && 
                    ( !inputLastName.getText().toString().equals("")) && 
                    ( !inputEmail.getText().toString().equals("")) )
            {
                if ( inputUsername.getText().toString().length() > 4 ){
                NetAsync(view);

                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Username should be minimum 5 characters",    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "One or more fields are empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
   }
/**
 * Async Task to check whether internet connection is working
 **/

private class NetCheck extends AsyncTask<String,String,Boolean>
{
    private ProgressDialog nDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        super.onPreExecute();
        nDialog = new ProgressDialog(Register.this);
        nDialog.setMessage("Loading..");
        nDialog.setTitle("Checking Network");
        nDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        nDialog.setCancelable(true);
        nDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... args){


  /**
  * Gets current device state and checks for working internet connection by     trying Google.
 **/
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)      getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected()) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
                HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlc.setConnectTimeout(3000);
                urlc.connect();
                if (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                    return true;
                }
            } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return false;

    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean th){

        if(th == true){
            nDialog.dismiss();
            new ProcessRegister().execute();
        }
        else{
            nDialog.dismiss();
            registerErrorMsg.setText("Error in Network Connection");
        }
    }
}





private class ProcessRegister extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject>      {

 /**
  * Defining Process dialog
 **/
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    String email,password,fname,lname,uname;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        inputUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.uname);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pword);
           fname = inputFirstName.getText().toString();
           lname = inputLastName.getText().toString();
            email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
            uname= inputUsername.getText().toString();
            password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Register.this);
        pDialog.setTitle("Contacting Servers");
        pDialog.setMessage("Registering ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {


    UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
    JSONObject json = userFunction.registerUser(fname, lname, email, uname,     password);

        return json;


    }
   @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
   /**
    * Checks for success message.
    **/
            try {
                if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                    registerErrorMsg.setText("");
                    String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);

                    String red = json.getString(KEY_ERROR);

                    if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
                        pDialog.setTitle("Getting Data");
                        pDialog.setMessage("Loading Info");

                        registerErrorMsg.setText("Successfully Registered");


                        DatabaseHandler db = new     DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                        JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");

                        /**
                         * Removes all the previous data in the SQlite database
                         **/

                        UserFunctions logout = new UserFunctions();
                        logout.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                        db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_FIRSTNAME),json_user.getString(KEY_LASTNAME),json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL),json_user.getString(KEY_USERNAME),json_user.getString(KEY_UID),json_user.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT));
                        /**
                         * Stores registered data in SQlite Database
                         * Launch Registered screen
                         **/

                        Intent registered = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Registered.class);

                        /**
                         * Close all views before launching Registered screen
                        **/
                        registered.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                        startActivity(registered);


                          finish();
                    }

                    else if (Integer.parseInt(red) ==2){
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                        registerErrorMsg.setText("User already exists");
                    }
                    else if (Integer.parseInt(red) ==3){
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                        registerErrorMsg.setText("Invalid Email id");
                    }

                }


                    else{
                    pDialog.dismiss();

                        registerErrorMsg.setText("Error occured in registration");
                    }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();


            }
        }}
    public void NetAsync(View view){
        new NetCheck().execute();
    }}
```

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/regular-expressions/how-to-validate-email-address-with-regular-expression/

Comment: You want us to do your job instead of you?

Comment: duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1819142/how-should-i-validate-an-e-mail-address question

Comment: What have you tried? And what exactly are you trying to do here? Client side validation can only tell you it looks like an email that exists, not whether the address is real and used.

Answer (score 1):

Email address can be validated b using the regular expressions.

```
 String EMAIL_PATTERN =
            "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@"
            + "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";
```

For example :

```
public boolean isValidEmail(String email){
        String EMAIL_PATTERN =
                "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@"
                        + "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";
        return email.matches(EMAIL_PATTERN);
    }
```

Comment: [Be careful using regex to validate emails](http://stackoverflow.com/a/201378/264775). it's easy to be overly restrictive.

Answer (score 0):

Add this method to your activity:

```
public final static boolean isValidEmail(String email) {
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches();
    }
}
```

And use it in your

```
btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {...}});
```

method like this:

```
if(isValidEmail(inputEmail.getText().toString()){
    //go ahead
} else {
    //make toast for example
}
```

Comment: Many Thanks Gabriella, its working fine :)

Answer (score 0):

***You can use below code which can be helpful for you:-***

```
    if(android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(EMAIL).matches())
     {
     // Perform action which you want after vaild email id
     }
   else
    {
     Toast.makeText(CONTEXT, "Please enter vaild email id", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Comment: yes got it it works fine tnx

Comment: @PrinsPrem ..Please mark answer right...if it is workable for you...