# How to validate an email address' specific domain?

Tags: android, pattern-matching

I've seen solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7882950/3183924) to validate whether an email address is formatted correctly, however I would like to check if an email address uses a specific domain such as "@gmail.com".  The example I am referring to which validates email address format in general is:

```
public final static boolean isValidEmail(CharSequence target) {
  if (TextUtils.isEmpty(target)) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(target).matches();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might use `endsWith` and use `@gmail.com` like:

```
"test@gmail.com".endsWith("@gmail.com")
```

Or use a regex like [`^\S+@gmail\.com$`](https://regex101.com/r/ALtonZ/1)

**Details**

- `^` Assert position at the start of the line
- `\S+` Match any non whitespace characters one or more times
- `@gmail\.com` match `@gmail.com`
- `$` Assert position at the end of the line

For example

```
if ("test@gmail.com".matches("^\\S+@gmail\\.com$")) {
    System.out.println("Match!");
}
```

[Demo Java](http://rextester.com/SYFCAW79553)

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of regex.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*@gmail\.com");
Matcher m = p.matcher("hello@gmail.com");
boolean b = m.matches();
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be checking if the email contains the specified domain. Later you could add a regex or even a dictionary to store the different domains, instead of using one method for each individual domain.

```
private boolean isFromGmailDomain(String email, String domain)
{
    return email.contains(domain);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of regex.
You can check regex https://www.regextester.com/94044

^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+.)?[a-zA-Z]+.)?(domain.in|domain2.com)