# How to check if a string is a valid email in android?

Tags: kotlin, string-matching, email-validation

I'm trying to handle error cases in my android app while signing up users. I want to make sure the email address provided is valid and by valid I mean the correct format : "something@something.com".

I have searched on google and stackoverflow, but couldn't find an exact answer in Kotlin.

Comment: If Kotlin supports regular expressions you can google for that, there is plenty of info available online on how to use a regular expression to validate an email address

Comment: https://gist.github.com/ironic-name/f8e8479c76e80d470cacd91001e7b45b
I am not sure with the kotlin but normally we use regex to validate it .

Comment: please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/7882950/5909412

Answer (score 24):

Based on this answer in java ([How should I validate an e-mail address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1819142/how-should-i-validate-an-e-mail-address/7882950#7882950)), you can use extension function to check the validity in kotlin.

```
fun String.isEmailValid(): Boolean {
    return !TextUtils.isEmpty(this) && android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(this).matches()
}
```

and then call

```
val str = ""
str.isEmailValid()
```

Comment: Has issues with different languages it seems.