# How should I validate an email address in Kotlin multiplatform mobile(KMM)?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile

How should we validate Kotlin multiplatform mobile(KMM)? I found this question but it used java.util.regex.Pattern and it is not useful for KMM:

[How should I validate an e-mail address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1819142/how-should-i-validate-an-e-mail-address)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Kotlin Regex class to validate an email address

```
 /**
 * Email address pattern, same as [android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS]
 */
private val emailAddressRegex = Regex(
    "[a-zA-Z0-9\\+\\.\\_\\%\\-\\+]{1,256}" +
            "\\@" +
            "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\\-]{0,64}" +
            "(" +
            "\\." +
            "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\\-]{0,25}" +
            ")+"
)


if (email.matches(emailAddressRegex)){
   //Valid email address
}
```