# validate an email without firebase auth - Kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

Is there any simple way to validate an email in kotlin without using firebase authentication? Need to validate an email before entering firebase.

Ex:- if a user fill the email field like **abcdefg** without **@** need to display error message. if a user fill the email field like **abc@gmail.com** then those data will enter to the firebase.

like this:- (other fields like name, Phone number)

```
if (FullName.text.trim().isNotEmpty() && PhoneNo.length()
                    .equals(10) && PhoneNo.text.trim().isNotEmpty()){

}
else{

Toast.makeText(this, "fill all required details", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

}
```

Comment: Hey AJK, what do you mean about email validation ? can you give some example for better understanding

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1819142/how-should-i-validate-an-e-mail-address/69663637#69663637 Try this link, i wrote code for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write this function.

```
private fun isItEmail(email: String): Boolean {
        return !TextUtils.isEmpty(email) && Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()
    }
```

then call `isItEmail("yourEmail@email.com")`  function with your email string. If it return true, then it is a valid email like `yourEmail@email.com` else it return false then you can Toast it is not valid email.